# PHP MVC profile update

Tags: php

Guys i have error in my php mvc code when am updating my profile it tell me error while updating l check my well but it seem am suck and don't know what to do. please help me!

it keep on warning me with this warning
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\php.dev\classes\Model.php on line 37

This my classes/Model.php file

```php
abstract class Model {
    protected $dbh;
    protected $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    // binds the prepare statement
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;

                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultSet() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function emailExist() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

and here's my controllers/user.php

```php
class Users extends Controller{
    protected function profile(){
        if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {//if user do not login they can not profile page
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');
        }
        $viewmodel = new UserModel();
        $this->returnView($viewmodel->profile(), true);
    }
}
```

and here's my models/user.php code

```php
public function profile(){
    // Sanitize POST
    //$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(isset($_POST['updateProfile'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
            Messages::setMsg('Please Fill All Form Fields', 'error');
            return;
        }

        // check if email is already taken
        $this->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $this->bind(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $row = $this->emailExist();
        if ($row) {
            Messages::setMsg('Email already Exist', 'error');
            return;
        } else {
            # Update the MySQL
            $this->query("UPDATE users SET name =:name, email =:email WHERE id =:id");
            $this->bind(':name', $_POST['name']);
            $this->bind(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $this->execute();
            // Verify
            if($this->lastInsertId()){
                Messages::setMsg('Successfull Updated', 'success');
                return;
            } else {
                Messages::setMsg('Error while updating data', 'error');
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

and here's my views/users/profile.php code

```php
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['name'];?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['email'];?>" />

            <!-- input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="<!?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['id']?>" / -->
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="updateProfile" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: you are only binding `:name` and `:email` you forgot to bind the `:id`

Comment: Essentially if the user already exists, nothing happens. If the user doesn't exist, it tries to update a user, using an ID that's not set.

Comment: but l enter a new email that not exist bu still it tell me error while updating user and it won't even update in the database a suck

Comment: no am not attempting to add a new user

Answer (score 0):

If the user *doesn't* already exist, it runs:

```php
$this->query("UPDATE users SET name =:name, email =:email WHERE id =:id");
```

Which is attempting to update an existing user, instead of adding a new one. The query fails with an error because you haven't bound anything to `:id` (and you shouldn't, because you're attempting to add a new user).

Instead try this query:

```
INSERT INTO users SET name =:name, email =:email
```

and it should work. It still won't allow you to *edit* users, but it will allow you to add new ones.

Comment: no am not attempting to add a new user look as this l bind the :id and still it give me error l want to update my data not adding new user. user can update his/her data but when l  try it does not work

Comment: You're still only hitting that path if the email doesn't already exist in the database.